# populate a html selectbox with jquery from pipe-symbol separated data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a variable with this value 'a|mike||c|John||d|Pierre'

(the a ,b and c are guid's and not letters in real)

now i want to populate a html select element with the id 'officers' with options with the 'a' as value and the name as text.

i'm stuck with the split on the |, the arrays and the jquery to populate the list....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var outer = myString.split('||');
var select = $('<select></select>');
var options = '';
for(var i = 0; i < outer.length; i++)
{
 var inner = outer[i].split('|')
 options += '<option value="' + inner[0] + '">' + inner[1]+  '</option>';
}
select.html(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add an option with jquery is http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var outer = myString.split('||');
var select = $('<select></select>');
for(var i = 0; i < outer.length; i++)
{
 var inner = outer[i].split('|')
 select.append('<option value="' + inner[0] + '">' + inner[1]+  '</option>');
}
```